# Plotting Candle-chart from csv file

Tags: matlab, csv, candlestick-chart

I have a .csv file which contains stock information of Amazon

```
date,       closePrice, volume,  openPrice, highPrice, lowPrice
=============================================================== 
30/10/2013  361.08      4500014  362.62     365         358.65
29/10/2013  362.7       2184755  358.96     362.89      356.29
28/10/2013  358.16      3602497  359.92     362.75      357.2
25/10/2013  363.39      12034820 358.6      368.4       352.62
24/10/2013  332.21      5699188  329.63     332.6499    326.75
```

I have loaded this file into Matlab and now i would like to read data from this file in order to produce candlestick chart. this is what I done:

```
clear;
close all;

file = '/Users/Documents/MATLAB/Candlestick Chart/Amazon.csv';

candle (file(:,2), file(:,3),file(:,4),file(:,5), 'b', file(:,1))

 set(file(:,5), 'FaceColor', 'g')
 set(file(:,6), 'FaceColor', 'r')
```

when running .m file i am getting error saying:

```
Error using dlmread (line 139)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 2u) ==>
/10/2013,361.08,4500014,362.62,365,358.65\n

Error in csvread (line 48)
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);
```

I know the software is failing to convert date into vector, can anyone help me convert date into vector and plot a candle-chart. So in X access I want to display date and based on high, low, closing, opening price i want to plot a candle chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html?searchHighlight=textscan)

```
 fid = fopen(filename, 'r')
 C = textscan(fid, '%s%f%f%f%f%f', 'Headerlines', 2);
 fclose(fid)
```

then use vectors in `C{2}`, `C{3}`, ... for your plot.

Comment: It(C) creates something like this {2516x1 cell}{2516x1 cell}{2516x1 cell}{2516x1 cell}{2516x1 cell}. the first cell contains dates and other cells have 'Nan' written? I want all the data from my file not just date.

Comment: You may want to choose new textscan options (like Delimiter, en of line), or change to %s instead of %f to see what is read. Textscan stops when it can't read, so you must have length of Cs = number of csv lines.

Comment: actually the above code works fine but it adds all the data into a first column so {2516x1 cell}{2516x1 cell}... if i double click on first cell i get something like this: 28/10/2013,358.16,3602497,359.92,362.75,357.2 From this i was wondering can i plot a candlestick-chart so i know each data is separated by a comma so base on that can i plot a chart??

Comment: `DATE = C{1}; DATA1 = C{2}; DATA2 = C{3}; ...`.

Comment: i manage to solve the problem by doing something like this: textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s %s',1, 'delimiter',','); and i created another array that read decimals. Then it will stored everything in outCell veritable.N
Now how do i plot a candlestick-chart this is what i did: candle (outCell(:,5), outCell(:,6), outCell(:,2), outCell(:,4), 'b', outCell(:,1)). It gives me two errors first: Error using vertcat and second Error in candle (line 76). can you help me on this?

Comment: you need to have a column vector of scalars. If you type `outCell(:,5)` in the command window, it will display something, and you can check the nature or the "something" in the workspace (or type `whos ans`). Try to modify `outCell{:,5}` to get the correct format.

Comment: Sorry I have forgot to mention I have also try using {:,1} from the previous answer of yours, so i added something like this:  candle (outCell{:,5}..... outCell{:,4}, 'b', outCell{:,1}); but i am getting another error saying: Error using candle Too many input arguments. Something should be wrong with my candle method because I am sure Matlab is capable of handling 2517X6 amount of data.